# Javascript Dropdown Staying open

Tags: javascript, css

In my site I made a simple dropdown menu, but my problem is that it won't close if `mouseleave` happens on the `<span>` that triggers the dropdown.

Here is my code:

```js
//Find the dropdown span
var header = document.getElementById('drop');

//Find the ul with the links
var ul = document.getElementById('nav-dropdown');


//Get the width and apply it to the dropdown items
var width = drop.getBoundingClientRect().width;
ul.style.minWidth = width + "px";

//Round the corners on the last link
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-link');
links[links.length - 1].style.borderRadius = "0 0 7px 7px";

var open = 0;

//Onhover, display the dropdown;
header.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  ul.style.display = "block";

  header.style.borderRadius = "7px 7px 0 0";

  if (links[0].getBoundingClientRect().width > width) {
    links[0].style.borderRadius = "0 7px 0 0";
  }
  open = 1;
});

//When the mouse leaves the menu, close it.
ul.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  ul.style.display = "none";
  header.style.borderRadius = "7px";
  open = 0;
});

//What I've tried to fix it:
/*
header.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
 ul.style.display = "none";
  header.style.borderRadius = "7px";
});
*/
```

```css
/*Stylesheet for this stuff*/

* {
  font-family: arial;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: white;
}

a,
#drop {
  color: white;
}

a:hover {
  color: coral;
}

.header-links-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  background: rgb(63, 83, 95);
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  opacity: .8;
  z-index: 999;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

.header-links {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-links {
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.nav-link {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: #4471ba;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background: #4480ba;
  color: #d1d1d1;
}

#nav-dropdown {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 42px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-link {
  color: black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

.dropdown-link:hover {
  color: #000;
  background-color: #a7a7a7;
}

.dropdown-link:active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #3b8cfa;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-links-container">
  <h2 class="title">Title</h2>
  <div class="header-links">
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">SLAP</a></li>
      <li id="drop" class="nav-link"><span>Dropdown</span></li>
      <ul id="nav-dropdown" class="jim">
        <a href="#">
          <li class="dropdown-link">Link 1</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="dropdown-link">Link 2</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="dropdown-link">Longer Link</li>
        </a>
        <a href="#">
          <li class="dropdown-link">Vacuum</li>
        </a>
      </ul>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<p>
  Relavent JS lines start at Line 16
</p>
```

And here is the fiddle that might make more sense: https://jsfiddle.net/dLw1hu5n/6/

I've tried closing the dropdown like in the last code block, but then it won't stay open when you go to hover over the links. I've also tried making the menu close when the mouse hovers over the navbar div, but no luck there either.

Can I fix this or do I need to start from square 1?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dnwzg6b2/ .although It can be resolved without javascript

Answer (score 0):

[I would prefere to solve this via css](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp). However, in your case you can try the following:

```
  function displayDropdown() {
    ul.style.display = "block";

    header.style.borderRadius = "7px 7px 0 0";

    if (links[0].getBoundingClientRect().width > width) {
      links[0].style.borderRadius = "0 7px 0 0";
    }
        open = 1;
  }

  function hideDropdown() {
    ul.style.display = "none";
    header.style.borderRadius = "7px";
    open = 0;
  }

  //Onhover, display the dropdown;
  header.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    displayDropdown();
  });

  ul.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    displayDropdown();
  });

  //When the mouse leaves the menu, close it.
  ul.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    hideDropdown();
  });

  header.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    hideDropdown();
  });
```

Comment: I see, I just forgot to add an event listener on the ul to display. Makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is fine but your event listener for mouseleave needs to be on the enclosing div. This way your element stays open until you hover outside of the header

```
t.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    ul.style.display = "none";
    header.style.borderRadius = "7px";
    open = 0;
  });
```

What is `t`? 
`var t = document.getElementById(t);`

What element has id `T`? 
Try this fiddle to find out https://jsfiddle.net/dLw1hu5n/12/